# Replace Image in Pdf

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pdfium

I´m trying to replace Images in existing Pdf-documents.

I´ve tried using the [PDFium Component Suite for FireMonkey](https://www.winsoft.sk/fpdfium.htm).

With the following code i´ve managed to insert an image via the `AddPicture`-function. Unfortunately i can´t find a way to get the position of the existing image. Unfortunately the record `TPdfImage` only has the properties `Width`, `Height` and `Data`. Does someone have experience with those Components or done anything like this already?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  lImage: TPdfImage;
begin
  FPdf1.FileName := 'C:\Path_To_Pdf.pdf';
  FPdf1.PageNumber := 1;
  FPdf1.Active := True;

  for I := 0 to FPdf1.ImageCount - 1 do
  begin
    lImage := FPdf1.Image[I];
  end;

  FPdf1.AddPicture(ImageControl1.Bitmap, 20, 20, 100, 100);
  FPdf1.SaveAs('C:\Path_To_Pdf_Images.pdf');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found a solution for the problem. With PDFium you can iterate over the Objects in the Pdf and just check if the `ObjectType` is `otImage`.

With this sample i´m overriding all images in the pdf with the `Bitmap` in `ImageControl1`. I hope this might help someone else in the future.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  lImage: TPdfImage;
  lPdfRectangle: TPdfRectangle;
  lBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  FPdf1.FileName := '..\..\Test.pdf';
  FPdf1.PageNumber := 1;
  FPdf1.Active := True;

  for I := 0 to FPdf1.ImageCount - 1 do
  begin
    lImage := FPdf1.Image[I];
  end;

  for I := 0 to FPdf1.ObjectCount - 1 do
  begin
    if FPdf1.ObjectType[I] = TObjectType.otImage then
    begin
      lPdfRectangle := FPdf1.ObjectBounds[I];
      lBitmap := FPdf1.ObjectBitmap[I];

      FPdf1.AddPicture(ImageControl1.Bitmap, lPdfRectangle.Left, lPdfRectangle.Bottom,
          lPdfRectangle.Right - lPdfRectangle.Left, lPdfRectangle.Top - lPdfRectangle.Bottom);
    end;
  end;

  FPdf1.SaveAs('..\..\Test_replaced.pdf');
end;
```

Comment: Does not replace but override

Comment: Yes that´s true. But for my purpose this is sufficient.
Thank you for the clarification :)